# Are Systems apps and user apps with root access same?

Tags: android, android-permissions

If not, what are the differences?
I'm asking this for managing permissions for individual apps.
I know an app with root access can manage permissions. But, is it possible for system apps too?

Answer (score 1):

> Are Systems apps and user apps with root access same?

No.

> If not, what are the differences?

System apps are ones installed on the `/system` partition.

> is it possible for system apps too?

Not that I am aware of. You are welcome to sift through [the platform permissions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) and see if there are any with a `protectionLevel` of `system` that would somehow impact what you are trying to do.